# Приложение в скобках - в именительном падеже?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Из-за трагических перипетий истории в странах, где особенно активно производили манускрипты, – Франции, Италии, Фландрии, Голландии, Англии -- множество рукописей просто погибло.

Нужны ли здесь предлоги "во" и "в":  во Франции, в Италии, во Фландрии, в Голландии, Англии?

Франции, Италии, Фландрии, Голландии, Англии - это приложение?

Можно ли так написать: Из-за трагических перипетий истории в странах, где особенно активно производили манускрипты (во Франции, в Италии, во Фландрии, в Голландии, Англии), множество рукописей просто погибло.

Если это приложение и если его можно выделить скобками, то нужно названия стран согласовывать со словом "странах" или их надо ставить в именительном падеже согласно правилу:

§196. Согласование приложений
3. Не согласуются:
4) заключенные в скобки слова-вставки, относящиеся к предшествующему обобщающему слову, например: Чехов проявил себя как блестящий мастер художественного слова в самых разнообразных жанрах (рассказ, новелла, сценка-юмореска, пьеса).
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm

Answer (score 2):

Однородные члены предложения могут отделяться от обобщающего слова знаком тире , если они выполняют функцию приложения со значением уточнения. Если однородные члены находятся в середине предложения и возникает необходимость представить их как выражение попутного, уточняющего замечания, тире ставится с двух сторон.
В повторе предлога нет необходимости. Сравните: *Для всего, что существует в природе, – воды, воздуха, неба, облаков, солнца, дождей, лесов, болот, рек и озер, лугов и полей, цветов и трав – в русском языке есть великое множество хороших слов и названий*; *В четырёх городах Италии — Риме, Неаполе, Турине и Милане — приняла старт финальная часть футбольного чемпионата Европы*; *У большинства приволжских городов - Казани, Куйбышева, Саратова - правый берег нагорный, левый - низменный*.

Возможный вариант: *Из-за трагических перипетий истории в странах, где особенно активно производили манускрипты (Франция, Италия, Фландрия, Голландия, Англия), множество рукописей просто погибло*.

«Слова-вставки», выступающие в роли приложения и заключенные в скобки, не согласуются с обобщающим названием (поэтому их нужно писать в именительном падеже): *Фактические данные приводятся в различных публицистических жанрах (корреспонденция, очерк, статья)*.

Answer (score 2):

Лучший вариант: Из-за трагических перипетий истории в странах, где особенно активно производили манускрипты (Франция, Италия, Фландрии, Голландия, Англия) множество рукописей просто погибло.

**Пояснение**

1) Однородный  ряд содержит явно **добавочную информацию**, для передачи которой уместно обособление скобками.

2) Повтор нескольких предлогов нежелателен, но в то же время однородный ряд находится **на значительном расстоянии от обобщающего слова с предлогом**, что может затруднить определение падежа и понимание смысла.

3) Вставка же имеет свободную форму, **не требуется согласования в падеже и повтора предлога.**

Answer (score 1):

> Из-за трагических перипетий истории в странах, где особенно активно
>   производили манускрипты, – Франции, Италии, Фландрии, Голландии,
>   Англии -- множество рукописей просто погибло.

Можно, но предлог в парных тире напрашивается.

> Нужны ли здесь предлоги "во" и "в": во Франции, в Италии, во Фландрии,
>   в Голландии, Англии?

Весьма желательно

> Франции, Италии, Фландрии, Голландии, Англии - это приложение?

Думаю, что можно по-разному трактовать, но при таком пунктуационном оформлении логично считать приложением (в роли уточнения).

> Можно ли так написать: Из-за трагических перипетий истории в странах,
>   где особенно активно производили манускрипты (во Франции, в Италии, во
>   Фландрии, в Голландии, Англия), множество рукописей просто погибло.

Вполне можно. А в чем сомнение? Только падеж поправьте у Англии.

> Если это приложение и если его можно выделить скобками, то нужно
>   названия стран согласовывать со словом "странах" или их надо ставить в
>   именительном падеже согласно правилу:

Всяко можно. Но я бы тут **в скобках** написал в именительном, ибо проще и понятнее.

> §196. Согласование приложений 3. Не согласуются: 4) заключенные в
>   скобки слова-вставки, относящиеся к предшествующему обобщающему слову,
>   например: Чехов проявил себя как блестящий мастер художественного
>   слова в самых разнообразных жанрах (рассказ, новелла, сценка-юмореска,
>   пьеса). http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm скобки

Ну вот и я об этом. Нет смысла согласовывать. Вряд ли это правило императивное (или хотя бы грамматическое), ибо завязано на чисто оформительский момент, но стилистически лучше смотрится именительный, особенно когда иное требует предлога.